# InteliJ - Assigning xmx - Java Could not reserve enough space for object heap error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a computer that's running windows 7 with 8GB ram.

When I edit intelij bvm options and set the following I get the above error:

```
-Xms768m
-Xmx2g
```

Anything I can do in relation to memory management etc? InteliJ seems to be hogging a lot of CPU which is the reason I decided to increase it's xms param.

Comment: Are you running the 64 bit Java JDK? If not, do it.

Comment: when I run `java -version` it is saying 64 bit.

Comment: Anyone who votes this is unclear doesn't know enough about technical issues. Why would the jvm not be able to reserve space and how can someone work around it? OS memory management issue? etc.

Comment: When does the error occurr? When you compile? What type of app are you compiling? What's 'bvm'?

Comment: Are you sure you have 2gb free memory? Try setting it lower. Also, I don't think upping memory allocation will do anything with CPU usage. Disabling plug-ins might.